# How to manage response when trying to connect to a server?

Tags: c#, sockets, xamarin, response

I am new to socket stuff and i am just trying to connect to a server and getting a response. Here is my code :

```
IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(address, port);
Socket tempSocket = new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
tempSocket.Connect(ipe);
```

So when i do that the server (delphi) is doing this:

```
Socket.SendText(#2+'D'+'ERRO GMT! Terminal '+Socket.RemoteAddress+' nao cadastrado.'+#3);
```

But i don't really know hot to receive that response after doing that socket.Connect.
Is it possible to get that?

Comment: I am not sure if I would use Socket but to receive you probably should use BeginReceive: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145132(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What would you use? TCPClient or something like that? I am open to sugestions i just need to try a connection and get that response somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick sample using TcpListener server + TcpClient. The asynchronous stuff looks much better on async function (not so much on console). client.GetStream().ReadAsync is reading the server response.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // sample listener
        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1334);
        listener.Start ();
        listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient ((ar) => 
            {
                var l = ar.AsyncState as TcpListener;

                if (l != null)
                {
                    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes ("Hello World!");
                    l.EndAcceptTcpClient (ar).GetStream ().Write (bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }, 
            listener);

        // async client
        var client = new TcpClient ();

        var connection = client.ConnectAsync("localhost", 1334);

        connection.Wait ();

        if (!connection.IsFaulted)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[1024];
            var res = client.GetStream ().ReadAsync (buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            res.Wait ();

            if (!res.IsFaulted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine (Encoding.UTF8.GetString (buffer));
            }
        }
    }
```